# How to determine which of two metals will have the higher temperature after applying the same amount of thermal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

> Two metal samples, $\mathrm{X}$ and $\mathrm{Z}$, of the same mass and initially at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$, are heated so that each metal receives the same amount of thermal energy, which metal will have the highest final temperature?
>   Specific heat capacities: 
>   $c(\mathrm{X}) = \pu{0.35 J//g*K}$,
>   $c(\mathrm{Z}) = \pu{0.895 J//g*K}$

Does the specific heat capacity matter in the final temperature or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the heat capacity is the energy required for a body to be warmed by $\pu{1 K}$. For the specific heat capacity it's the same but normalized by the mass. The higher the heat capacity is, the more energy will be required to warm it.

The metal $\mathrm{X}$ having the lowest heat capacity will have the higher temperature if it receives the same amount of energy than the metal $\mathrm{Z}$.